# Why are some Americans more religious than European counterparts?

Tags: united-states, europe, religion

What are some of the historical reasons for why certain Americans are more religious than similar Europeans? For example, there are pronounced differences in [Church attendance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_attendance); [Extent of belief in god](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_atheism).

To narrow things down, let us restrict 'America' to Protestant America and 'Europe' to Protestant Europe. (I have written it this way, since historically the majority of early American settlers arriving prior to 1800 have come from the Protestant regions of Europe.)

Comment: Why the close vote?

Comment: This is an important question with implications for history. The common answer is colonists chose their religion, while European monarchs chose the religion of their countries.  Why this has persisted is a subject of continuing research.

Comment: @RazieMah: "Historically the majority of Americans have come from the Protestant regions of Europe." That's true of the early "settlers" (whose families came before 1800). I did my best to "patch" the question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: If the comment by you (attached) is accurate then isn't the question eminently **unsuitable** for the site, due to no answer possibly existing: "Why this has persisted is a subject of continuing research."

Comment: This is a very good question, I just have no idea how to answer it.  I would also say that the Protestant specification is not necessary and may distract from the point. People from Jewish families are more religious on average than those in Europe.  People from Catholic families are also more religious on average that those who stayed in Europe. What is it about American culture that both undermines traditional religion and buttresses it?

Comment: @Kenny The short answer is communism and fascism. Both occurred in Europe and not much in the US. By removing Catholics, you're removing the French and the French Revolution, which makes its a bit hard to answer. They were very anti religion.

Comment: There can be no answer because there is no objective definition of **more religious**, and it defines that we are to compare two alike groups, except for their "religiousness". **The question cannot be saved.**

Comment: I think this would be a good question if you left out the word "some" in the title line. I think that at a statistical level the percentage of regular church goers in the USA is higher than in Western European countries (including the Catholic countries). The reasons for this are worth discussing.

Answer (score 4):

traditionally, Europeans were told what to believe in, Americans came to American to believe in things of their own choosing.
Of course this is not wholly the case any more, many European countries are as religiously liberal as the US are now. But a strong monoculture exists in those countries still, with the majority of churches being of a specific denomination.

And of course at least on paper many European countries still have an "official religion", usually the one held to by their royal family. 
Enforcement of these religions on the population may no longer happen, but remember that the last of the organisations like the Spanish Inquisition were disbanded only a few decades ago (though the Spanish Inquisition was officially ended in 1834, some of the laws under which it and similar organisations elsewhere operated existed well into the 20th century).
Many would flee from such things, often to the Americas. The sacrifice of doing so was high, high enough that it stands to reason that it would be those of very strong religious beliefs would be the more likely to go to the Americas rather than convert (at least in public) to the official religion of their home countries.
Leaving everything behind for an uncertain future in a rough, violent, country, rejected by your friends and family, probably with a death sentence over your head if you give up to return to Europe isn't something for the faint of heart.

And those of strong religious conviction (rather than those who are religious in order to be accepted by their society) are more likely to pass on that conviction to their children.

Comment: "And of course at least on paper many European countries still have an "official religion", usually the one held to by their royal family." Coold you give some examples? I live in Belgium and a country with an official religion in europe sounds very strange to me.

Comment: @JeroenK think the UK where the Church of England is still the official religion (at least in England). In fact the king or queen is by definition head of the Church of England. In Spain the Roman Catholic church was the state religion until 1978, in Sweden until 2000. Of course there's not been enforcement of that (by the way of criminal prosecution for people adhering to other religions) for quite some time.

Comment: @JeroenK - Check on the [wikipedia page on State Religon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_religion). Europe is one of essentially 3 areas of the world that still have them. However, the other two areas aren't exactly notable for their lack of belief in God, so I have to think there's something else behind this.

Comment: @T.E.D. Thanks, I did not know that. When new american citizen's have to swear the [oath of allegiance ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oath_of_citizenship_(United_States)) with the last part: "so help me god", is that not an informal note on state religion?

Comment: @T.E.D. well, it doesn't matter much if a state doesn't have an official religion, if it lacks many other basic liberties.

Comment: @JeroenK it isn't, and for long it's been optional and a non-religious variant has been available. A state religion would be a state requiring its citizens to be for example Roman Catholic and punishing those that aren't. The USA by the constitution doesn't have that. The wording of the phrase "so help me god" doesn't say which god, a major difference. It's not like Saudi Arabia or Iran where you are by law required to be a Muslim and can be put in jail (or even killed) if you're not.

Comment: @jwenting So by that definition in Europe there aren't any state religions either. BTW are you alowed not to ask for the help of "a" god? Or multiple gods?

Comment: @JeroenK You are not required to swear by God, no. Although most of the reason for this is because some Christians believe it is a violation of the Matthew 5:34.

Comment: I think the theory helps explain why the US is religious, but it doesn't explain why Europeans are not. I simply don't agree with the bottom up theory here. Atheism started and was promoted and many cases forced on people violently by intellectuals and elites in Europe.

Comment: @RazieMah that came later, in the late 19th and early 20th century. Was part of the communist movement which never gained much ground in the US until the early 21st century. And now we see in the US as well an increasing movement to force people away from religion through laws and lawsuits.

Comment: Required by law in Iran to be a muslim? Whilst this is certainly true of Saudi Arabia, it is most certainly not the case with Iran, where there are minorities of Christians and jews, not to mention the fact there are churches and synagogues